# Animated show about scrooge-type character and masked man

Tags: story-identification, tv, episode-identification

I saw this a very long ago as a child (early-mid 1990s, probably European or American but syndicated in India); it was an animated TV series for children, showing a different fairy tale every episode.

In this episode there's a town, and the town is celebrating a festival. Everybody is very happy and is enjoying the festival, but there is one person in particular who's a bit of a Scrooge -- he doesn't enjoy the festival, and doesn't enjoy the merrymaking. He wants nothing to do with it. The villagers know he's like this, and generally avoid him.

That festival day, a man knocks on the Scrooge's door. This is where my memory gets hazy...

If I recall correctly, the two get into some sort of challenge or competition or show... the visitor takes off his mask, only to reveal a mask underneath. And the mask underneath is taken off, to reveal another mask, and so on and so forth.

Eventually the visitor leaves... and the Scrooge takes off *his own mask*, revealing the face of a devil.

Anyway, that's what I remember, and I might have mixed up the details. Been trying to track down this TV series for decades. Does anyone know what this is?